# Example of a nowhere dense set in a space but not in another

Tags: general-topology

In the Wikipedia entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set one can read the following statement:

> The surrounding space matters: a set $A$ may be nowhere dense when considered as a subset of a topological space $X$, but not when considered as a subset of another topological space $Y$.

What is an example of such a set?

Comment: Any subset of the Cantor set is nowhere dense in the reals, but there are plenty of subsets of the Cantor set that are not nowhere dense in the Cantor set. Aside from the trivial example of the Cantor set itself, the set of endpoints of complementary intervals is not nowhere dense in the Cantor set (in fact, this set is actually **dense** in the Cantor set). More generally, let $N$ be nowhere dense in $X$ and let $D$ be a dense-in-$N$ subset of $N.$ Then $D$ is nowhere dense in $X$ and $D$ is not nowhere dense in $N.$

Comment: The following paper (I have a (presumably) finalized manuscript copy, obtained back in 2001, if anyone is interested) may be of interest: Ondřej Zindulka, *A nowhere dense set is deeply nowhere dense*, **Questions and Answers in General Topology** 17 (1999), pp. 89-90 (MR 2000a:54040; [Zbl 936.54029](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0936.54029)). Also, Theorem 4 in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/real-analysis-exchange/volume-21/issue-2/Porosity-nowhere-dense-sets-and-a-theorem-of-Denjoy/rae/1339694085.full) gives a more precise porosity version of the key lemma in Zindulka's paper.

Answer (score 1):

The next sentence gives a trivial example: "Notably, a set is always dense in its own subspace topology." So take any nowhere dense set, and it will be dense in its own subspace topology.

Answer (score 0):

For instance, $\{0\}$ is nowhere dense as a subset of $\Bbb Q$, if we consider in $\Bbb Q$ its usual topology. But it is not nowhere dense as a subset of $\Bbb Q$, if we consider in $\Bbb Q$ the discrete topology.